# Android Clean architecture - on which layer should I put given functionality

Tags: android, architecture, clean-architecture

Imagine, that we have Android application, which is splitted by groups:

- Presentation - which concerns fragments, viewmodels and view-specific logic
- Domain - concerns use cases and interfaces, code is library and framework - independent
- Data - storing and retrieving data, e.g. from database and REST API

And then there is a need to implement a library, which is responsible for communication with specific hardware, and stores states about it. This library should be used in domain layer, and will be used by implementation of interface from domain layer.

My question is: on which layer should we place implementation of this library? Data layer should be ok for that, or we should create additional layer - if yes, how should we name it?

Comment: When you say library, do you mean that this is going to be a separate module?

The way I think about it is: 1) Create the library as a separate module, 2) Define the interfaces for inter-module communication in the domain layer (dependency inversion), 3) Implement those interfaces in the library module & finally (4) use the implementations (i.e. through D.I.) in your domain layer.

Comment: Yes, exactly, implementation of this library will be in a separate module, and it will use interfaces and data defuined in domain layer. My question is: to which layer this module should belong? To data or should we create another layer?

Comment: I'm guessing that by “belong”, you're referring to which layer/module should use it? If so, I'd guess that it depends on what the library itself will do and/or what the exposed functionality of it is. For example, let's assume that the lib is going to be communicating with hardware and that you want to store its state somehow. You could use the domain layer for its entities & the data layer for storage ops or any framework-specific operations. That way, your domain module remains pure.

Comment: Ok, but imagine that we have to start some operation in this library (and also we would like to have it in domain layer) by void function. I have some doubts if it fits into data layer, because typically this layer is used for storing and retrieving data (like form databases or by REST API), and in that case we want to start some operation without having any result. Retrieving state we can treat as gathering some data I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean, Onion, and Hexagonal Architecture are different names for the same thing. However, they each have a unique vocabulary, designed to drive you to different blogs and books. Therefor I must point out that Clean Architecture doesn't have a domain layer. That term comes from Onion Architecture.

In any case, no. A "library, which is responsible for communication with specific hardware" belongs in the outermost layer. Whether you want to call that layer adapter<sup>[=](https://reflectoring.io/images/posts/spring-hexagonal/hexagonal-architecture_hu6764515d7030d45af6f7f498c79e292b_50897_956x0_resize_box_3.png)</sup>, infrastructure<sup>[=](https://anarsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Onion-Architecture.png)</sup>, or device drivers<sup>[=](https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*0u-ekVHFu7Om7Z-VTwFHvg.png)</sup>.